# Fancybox remove added styles

Tags: jquery, styles, fancybox

I am using Fancybox 2 on a site and noticed when I Inspect Element, some of the divs have a "style" attribute with some CSS in there.

All of this I can do in my styles.css, so I would like to know how to remove these added "style" attributes, or at least remove things like padding and top / left positioning.

Comment: Edit Fancybox 2 directly to remove the styles?

Comment: Theoretically you would not remove them.  You would override them.  We need to see code, however, to provide further assistance.

Comment: I think you can do this `$('.theElement').css('the-declaration','');`

Comment: See Fancybox docs. There are attributes for padding, margin, etc you can set/configure : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Okay so using padding : 0 was easy enough, but there is no option in Fancybox for changing the "left" positioning. So I tried to use: $('.fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-desktop, .fancybox-type-inline, .fancybox-opened').css('left', 0); and that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a JSfiddle by chance, or would it be relatively easy to create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updating to say that, after trying everything, there seems to be no way at all to remove the inline styles added by Fancybox. I am accepting this as the correct answer, even though it really isn't much of an answer. If anyone does find a solution, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by adding the following code:
$("#div_for_overlay").css({'width': '800px', 'height': '400px'});

And setting padding:0 in the fancibox.js file instead of padding:15px

This removed the inline styles for fancybox-overlay

To remove the same for fancybox-inner and fancybox-outer divs, just do the same.  See if you can edit with some jquery code like so 
$(".fancybox_outer").css({'width': '800px', 'height': '400px'});

And if not, find where it is being set in the fancybox.js file and edit inline.
That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery [.CSS()](http://api.jquery.com/CSS/) to set the padding to 0, or use [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to remove all styling and you could add your own class to it.